# Subsetting pandas dataframe for identical value on several consecutive columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame of the following type;

```
id | a | b | c | d | e | g
---------------------------

1  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1  | 1

2  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1  | 0

3  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1  | 1
```

I want to filter rows which has zero for all columns, `a` through `d`. I am aware that this can be achieved by;

```
data[data['a']==0 & data['b']==0 & data ['c'] ==0 & data ['d'] ==0]
```

But is there a quicker way using `iloc` or `loc` to achieve the same. For example, I tried the following;

```
data.iloc[:,[1:4]==0]
```

But it gave me following error message; `ValueError: Can only index by location with a [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array]`

Any alternate feedback/advice, which can replace my original solution is appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
df[df.iloc[:,1:4].eq(0).all(1)]
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply.may I know what does `all(1)` mean here? thanks

Comment: `all(1)` is equivalent to `all(axis=1)`, that is check if all the values are `True` row-wise. `all(axis=0)` checks if all the values are `True` column-wise.